# EJS Failed to lookup view "exercises" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm building a fitness tracking application using Node.js and Express.js. I'm trying to render a view called exercises.ejs from the views directory, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "exercises" in views directory "C:\Users\burak\Desktop\Fitness_Tracker\views"
```

Here's the directory structure of my app:

```
├── app
│   ├── Controllers
│   ├── Routes
│   └── views
│       ├── index.ejs
│       └── exercises.ejs
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── server.js
```

My index.js file in app js is like that:

```
import express from "express"
import routes from '../app/Routes/index';
import ejs from 'ejs'
import path from 'path'

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('ejs', ejs.renderFile);

app.use('/', routes);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('index', { title: 'My Website', message: 'Welcome to my website!' });

})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

and I can reach home directory.

But my Exercise.js controller file don't see the views/exercises.ejs path
Here is my controller code:

```
import db from '../../src/models/index'

import express from "express"
import path from 'path'
import ejs from 'ejs'

const app = express();

// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

class ExerciseController{

  static async getAll(req, res) {
    try {
    const allExercises = await db.Exercises.findAll();

    res.render('exercises', {exercises: allExercises});
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
  }

  static async addExercise(req, res) {
    try {
      const exercise = await db.Exercises.create(req.body);
      return res.status(201).json({
        exercise,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  }


}

export default ExerciseController;
```

I've double-checked that the view file exists and that the path is correct, but I'm still getting this error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem thanks !
res.render(`${path.join(__dirname, '../views/exercises')}`, {exercises: allExercises,title:'Exercise'});